# C# in registry, the key exists, but the value is null

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I got the data from the registry, the key exists, but the value I got is `null`, I don't know why happened? I tried to change the permissions, but it's still `null`.
But I copied the code in a new project, it could get the value.

I debugged the project  attached to process, the pop windows showed that it needed the `Admin` permission.

Comment: Sounds like permission issue. What exactly have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: Right-click on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as Administrator" (assuming you have admin privileges).

Comment: @micalk I create a new project  and run it by different identity, admin, users , It's OK , I could get  the  Registry data, then I debugged the different projects which same code,                                        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser;  Run as Administrator.
            RegistryKey softWare = rk.OpenSubKey("Software");
            RegistryKey microsoft = softWare.OpenSubKey("VB and VBA Program Settings");                  rk.SubKeyCount==13 , it's right . but the old project just 8 subkeycount.

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy It's running as admin. but I could not get the registry data. RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser; Run as Administrator. RegistryKey softWare = rk.OpenSubKey("Software"); RegistryKey microsoft = softWare.OpenSubKey("VB and VBA Program Settings");   microsoft is null , I could not get the "VB and VBA Program Settings" vlaue. I don't konw why the "rk.SubKeyCount" is wrong, it's 8 .  I create a new project with same code, the rk.SubKeyCount is 13. I don't know why.

Comment: @PaulShang: I think it would be more helpful for everyone if you posted your code in the question

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy , thx  for your answer, I checked the code , It's OK ,  the cause is that the code in the Windows Service Project . RegistryKey rk = Registry;  rk -> HKEY_USERS-.DEFAULT.            In the Console project , rk-> HKEY_CURRENT_USER,  they are two different Registries.  I  need the data from Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  But  in my Windows Service Project , I don't know how to get the them from the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  Thanks.